# Re-writing CSS in Styled-Components

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, styled-components

I am currently working on a project which involves a dropdown menu, and I am following a tutorial. An issue that I encountered is with the dynamic styling of the dropdown.

```
<ul className={`dropdown ${dropdown ? "show" : ""}`}>
```

this is the code from the tutorial, my question is how can I rewrite it using styled-components?

// my Dropdown component

```
const Dropdown = ({ submenus, dropdown }) => {
  return (
    <StyledDropdown dropdown={dropdown}>
      {submenus.map((submenu, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <a href="/">{submenu.title}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </StyledDropdown>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

//styling of dropdown

```
export const StyledDropdown = styled.ul``;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get props in styled components

```js
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

export const StyledDropdown = styled.ul`
  ${props => props.dropdown ? css`
    // Style for show
  ` : ''}
`;
```